# Поиск по первой букве в строке

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Есть строка с содержимым

```
Кроссовки Адидас Найк 5-П-4
```

Нужно что-бы строку находило по буквам К,А,Н,5

Comment: `WHERE column RLIKE '(^| )[КАН5]'`. Если в поиске используется только одна буква, то квадратные скобки не нужны. Если используется служебный символ, его следует квотировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо больше пользователю Akina. Решение проблемы

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name RLIKE '(^| )Х'
```